# How to get value of plugin's params in module in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.1.5.

Inside my plugin, which is located in `plugins/content/myplugin/form/form.xml`, I have a form like this:

```
<form>
    <fields name="params">
      <fieldset name="category_fieldset" label="Category Fields">
          <field name="category_intro" type="textarea" 
                      id="category_intro" label="Category Intro" 
                      description="Intro text" />
      </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

This plugin is added to every category option in the admin.

In my module (`tmpl/default.php`), I tried to retrieve this value like below but I am not getting any result.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if (!empty($item)) {
      ......
      ......
      $plugin = &JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'myplugin');
      $pluginParams = new JRegistry($plugin->params);
      $param = $pluginParams->get('category_intro');
      echo $param;
      ......
      ......
  }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you're using to get the parameter, so it must be something to do with the `if` statement

Comment: Add a print_r($pluginParams); before $param = $pluginParams->get('category_intro');. What is the output?

Answer (score 1):

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is directly from Joomla's online wiki.  This code was inside the plugins construct method:

```
// Get the parameters.
if (isset($config['params']))
{
        if ($config['params'] instanceof JRegistry)
        {
            $this->params = $config['params'];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->params = new JRegistry;
            $this->params->loadString($config['params']);
        }
}
```

Here's the link:

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Developer_Overview